# How can I throw in the .then of a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following js express code:

```
app.get('/lists2', (req, res) => {
  mongo.getDB()
    .then(db => db.collection('dogs'))
    .then(collection => collection.find().toArray())
    .then(array => res.json(success(array)))
    // How can I throw in the middle of a promise to trigger express's middleware?
    .catch(error => {
      throw {message: "database error"};
    });
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  const message = err.message || 'Encountered a server error';
  const status = err.status || 500;
  res.status(status).json({status, message});
})
```

I have written a middleware error handler so I can trigger an API error response with `throw` the problem is I can't throw inside the `then` because it's inside async code, is there any method to get around this? Or is my error handling pattern incorrect?

Comment: @Andreas — Because it is async and the middleware that the OP wants to handle it is outside the promise chain.

Comment: @Andreas updated question.

Comment: Have you tried if calling `next` on the exception will work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `next` (cf. [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)):

```
app.get('/lists2', (req, res, next) => {
  mongo.getDB()
    .then(db => db.collection('dogs'))
    .then(collection => collection.find().toArray())
    .then(array => res.json(success(array)))
    // How can I throw in the middle of a promise to trigger express's middleware?
    .catch(error => {
      next(new Error("database error"));
    });
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  const message = err.message || 'Encountered a server error';
  const status = err.status || 500;
  res.status(status).json({status, message});
})
```